# Rails references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-key-relationship

Let's say that you have a foreign key called COMPANY_ID in the table PERSON.  In the model PERSON, can you write?

```
validates_presence_of :company_id
```

or

```
validates_presence_of :company
```

or

both?

Which is the preferred and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefere validates the foreign_key. It's better because there are no association made so 1 SQL request less.